# [Mockito][withObjectMocked]NoSuchFieldException: MODULE$

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I can't test a simple example of **withObjectMocked**, and I still get this exception :

*Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MODULE$*

Here my code

```
    object FooObject {
      def simpleMethod: Int = 1
    }
    "mock" should {
      withObjectMocked[FooObject.type] {
        when(FooObject.simpleMethod).thenReturn(1)
        FooObject.simpleMethod
        verify(FooObject).simpleMethod
      }
    }
```

I'm using :

- mockito-scala_2.12 : 1.16.25
- Scala 2.12
- Java version 1.8.0_.261

---

Update information:

The error is thrown in *MockitoAPI.scala* :

```
def withObjectMocked[O <: AnyRef: ClassTag](block: => Any): Unit = {
    val moduleField = clazz[O].getDeclaredField("MODULE$")
[...]
```

Comment: It is stated in the docs: `To enable withObjectMocked feature, it is mandatory to create the file src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker containing a single line:  mock-maker-inline` Did you do that?

Comment: yes I did. But one strange thing is that when I remove that file, I have the same error

Comment: I created a ScalaTest "Configuration" in Idea Intellij, and I didn't check "Use sbt".
When I did that, I get an error for launching